# Validar acceso a carpetas compartidas mediante Python

Tags: python, windows

La duda que me aflige es la siguiente:
Tengo acceso a una carpeta compartida en la red de mi trabajo, pero recorriendo esta carpeta,me encontré con que no cuento con acceso a todas las subcarpetas, por lo que necesito generar un listado de las carpetas a las que no tengo acceso, para indicarle al área de TIC cuales son las carpetas a las que me deben habilitar el acceso. Lo tengo que hacer de esta forma porque si no indico específicamente las carpetas, TIC lo que hace es darle de baja a los permisos de todas las carpetas y volverlos a habilitar y volvería al mismo punto, porque según ellos eso arregla el problema, pero ya lo han hecho anteriormente y no se arregla el problema, por lo que es mejor darles el listado específico.
Mi idea es hacerlo mediante Python, pero no tengo idea de como capturar el evento o el mensaje de si tengo o no acceso a la carpeta, lo intenté con el módulo os, y el uso de Try, pero no obtuve resultados.
Estoy abierto a cualquier sugerencia.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda comunidad.

Comment: Hubiese estado bueno ver que código estás intentando usar, bueno una forma sería recorrer la carpeta y después por medio de algo así :os.access('subcarpeta', os.R_OK) ves si tenés permiso o no

Comment: No coloqué el código porque no sabía que hacer, conozco como recorrer una ruta, pero no conocía la opción de validar si tengo acceso o no a la ruta. Me asalta otra duda, estuve revisando ejemplos de la opción que me das y la duda que me surge es: ¿Necesariamente debo darle un archivo? Lo que quiero decir es: ¿Hay forma de validar solamente la ruta a un directorio? Que es lo que necesito hacer, probé con os.acces sobre una carpeta a la que se que no tengo acceso y no me la mostró con la validación hecha. Igualmente gracias por tu ayuda @candid-moe